# Bootstrap grid system collapsing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug

at around 990px, I'm seeing my grid fold into one giant column.. I'd prefer it not do that and as you can see in the screencap there's a LOT of space to the right... Do I need to add a 2nd col?

[image: This grid looks okay]

[image: Suddenly I'm getting one big ol column]

```
.col-md-12.col-sm-6
btn.btn.btn-primary( ui-sref='menus.new')
    |Create New Menu

.row
    .col-md-2
        h4 KEY
    .col-md-2.hidden-sm
        h4 CREATED
    .col-md-3.col-md-offset-3
        h4 ACTIONS

.row.form-group( ng-repeat='menu in menus')
    .col-md-2
        | {{menu.key}}
    .col-md-2.hidden-sm
        | {{::menu.created | date : 'medium' }}
    .col-md-3.col-md-offset-2
        .row
            .col-md-6
                button.btn.btn-default.btn-block(ui-sref="menus.edit({id: menu._id})")
                    | Edit
            .col-md-6
                button.btn.btn-danger.btn-block(ng-click="removeMenu(menu._id, $index)")
                    | Delete
```

I've tried hiding the created column to no avail

Comment: Maybe `sm` classes instead of `md`?

Comment: tried that @makshh , but seems to just repeat the collapse at the `sm` breakpoint instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that when you try putting it in **900px** it detects that it should change for a mobile or a tablet. This is the special thing about **Bootstrap** it resizes everything for you, so you don't have to write media queries. The easiest way to do is, is to specify how many columns would you like when the screen goes "small", thus using the `col-sm-*`

The easiest way to solve it, is to embed an `col-sm- 'size you want from 1 to 12'` next to your `col-md-*`

Comment: I have sizes on every `sm` breakpoint, but still seeing this 1 column breakdown at the small breakpoint

Comment: actually I realized it... I need to hide each level explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Ok after tinkering I realized.. when you hide things in bootstrap you've got to call out each level explicitly that you want to hide.

And what you're seeing in my screen cap... is at the very small (aka `xs`) level.. everything I thought I was hiding is cramming back into rendered view.  BAH

The Fix Example :

```
.row
    .col-md-2
        h4 KEY
    .col-md-2.hidden-sm.hidden-xs
        h4 CREATED
```